# How to use Manifest with Enumeration in Scala?

Tags: scala, manifest, enumeration

If I have the following Scala code:

```
trait BaseTrait[EnumType <: Enumeration] {
    protected val enum: EnumType
    protected val valueManifest: Manifest[EnumType#Value]
}

object MyEnum extends Enumeration {
    val Tag1, Tag2 = Value
}
```

And I want to create a class which implements BaseTrait using MyEnum, I can do it like this:

```
class BaseClass[EnumType <: Enumeration]
(protected val enum: EnumType)
(implicit protected val valueManifest: Manifest[EnumType#Value])
extends BaseTrait[EnumType] {
}

class Test extends BaseClass(MyEnum)
```

But how can I do it without an intermediary base class? All other attempts always resulted in a compile error.

Comment: Why don't you use an `abstract class` instead of your `BaseTrait`?

Comment: The trait is from an API. I define myself the Enumeration and the class that implements the trait.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not write what you tried but my guess is that you had your class extend `BaseTrait[MyEnum]`. As `MyEnum` is an `object` the type `MyEnum` does not exist (unless you also define a class or trait with that name).

You have to explicitly supply the singleton type `MyEnum.type` as type parameter.

```
class Test extends BaseTrait[MyEnum.type] {
  protected val enum = MyEnum
  protected val valueManifest = manifest[MyEnum.type#Value]
}
```